# URLs not allowed error for one property, but not for the other?

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, search-engine-indexing, xml-sitemap

All of our XML sitemaps are located on another domain than the domain they're referring to, for instance:
- Sitemaps would be located at sitemap-domain.com/sitemap-1.xml
- URLs being referenced in those sitemaps would be located at main-domain.com

**+++ ISSUE 1 +++**
*URLs not allowed*
We verified ownership for both domains in the Search Console. There are tons of sitemaps where this worked fine for us, however, since Friday, there is one sitemap - let's call it "sitemap-index-fluff.xml" - where we get the "URL not allowed" error notice when submitting the index sitemap on our sitemap-domain.com.

Since all of our sitemaps can be accessed at each property/domain, we submitted the sitemap twice in the Search Console, once for each property:

- sitemap-domain.com/sitemap-index-fluff.xml
- main-domain.com/sitemap-index-fluff.xml

*Please note: All sitemaps referenced in sitemap-index-fluff.xml are still located at sitemap-domain.com, whereas all URLs within these sitemaps are located at main-domain.com. All sitemaps have been checked for syntax errors or 4xx/5xx/3xx status codes before submitting.*

Now this is what happened:
- The sitemap index located at sitemap-domain.com showed as many errors as URLs ("URLs not allowed").
- The sitemap index located at main-domain.com began with the same amount of errors. However, the number is reduced day by day, and the number of indexed pages (roughly 10% of what we submitted currently) as well. It just goes on ever so slowly.

Now I am wondering why this is working with our main-domain.com property and not with our sitemap-domain.com property, since this has been working fine with exactly the same setup for a lot of other sitemap indexes in the months? Any ideas on this?

**+++ ISSUE 2 +++**
*Sitemaps not clickable in the Search Console*
While we're at it, there's another error I have never come across before:   Whenever a sitemap the Search Console pulled from the sitemap index shows an error, you can usually click the sitemap (Crawl > Sitemaps > Sitemap index) and see the errors for each individual sitemap with some sample URLs.

Funny thing is: When submitting the sitemap index to our sitemap-domain.com property, the sitemaps are clickable as usual. When submitting the sitemap index to our main-domain.com property, Search Console still pulls all sitemaps from the sitemap index and shows the number of errors for each individual sitemap - but none of these are clickable.

Has anyone ever come across this issue? **Is this a Search Console bug,** or is this something we can fix by ourselves? If so, how?

Comment: are your sites placed on the same hosting? If yes, are they placed side by side or in the nesting folders? Like site a in /folder-a/, site b in /folder-a/folder-b/?

Comment: You cannot submit a sitemap for example.com that is not accessible on example.com and made available on otherexample.com.

Comment: @closetnoc: The sitemap is indeed accessible on both domains.

Comment: I just mentioned it JIC you were not aware. We get that issue here from time to time.